# Проблема с прошивкой STM32 через ST-LINK в Keil

Tags: микроконтроллеры, stm32, прошивка

```
#include "stm32f10x.h"

    int main(void){
    RCC->APB2ENT|=RCC_APB2_GPIOCEN;
    GPIOC->MODER |= GPIO_MODER_MODER8_0 | GPIO_MODER_MODER9_0;
    GPIOC->ODR = GPIO_ODR_8;
    for (int i=0; i<500000; i++){}
    GPIOC->ODR = GPIO_ODR_9;
    for (int i=0; i<500000; i++){}
    }
```

Не получается прошить STM32VLDiscovery. При Build пишет, что у меня 7 ошибок(хотя keil ничего не подчёркивает красным). При попытке прошить выскакивает ошибка: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код ошибок:

```
*** Using Compiler 'V5.06 update 6 (build 750)', folder: 'C:\Keil_v5\ARM\ARMCC\Bin'
Build target 'Target 1'
compiling main.c...
main.c(4): error:  #136: struct "<unnamed>"  has no field "APB2ENT"
  RCC->APB2ENT|=RCC_APB2_GPIOCEN;
main.c(4): error:  #20: identifier "RCC_APB2_GPIOCEN" is undefined
  RCC->APB2ENT|=RCC_APB2_GPIOCEN;
main.c(5): error:  #136: struct "<unnamed>"  has no field "MODER"
  GPIOC->MODER |= GPIO_MODER_MODER8_0 | GPIO_MODER_MODER9_0;
main.c(5): error:  #20: identifier "GPIO_MODER_MODER8_0" is undefined
  GPIOC->MODER |= GPIO_MODER_MODER8_0 | GPIO_MODER_MODER9_0;
main.c(5): error:  #20: identifier "GPIO_MODER_MODER9_0" is undefined
  GPIOC->MODER |= GPIO_MODER_MODER8_0 | GPIO_MODER_MODER9_0;
main.c(6): error:  #20: identifier "GPIO_ODR_8" is undefined
  GPIOC->ODR = GPIO_ODR_8;
main.c(8): error:  #20: identifier "GPIO_ODR_9" is undefined
  GPIOC->ODR = GPIO_ODR_9;
main.c: 0 warnings, 7 errors
".\Objects\Lesson_2.axf" - 7 Error(s), 0 Warning(s).
Target not created.
Build Time Elapsed:  00:00:01
```

Comment: Добавьте сюда весь текст ошибок. Ошибки могут быть не только в этом тексте программы, но и в настройках включений, компоновщика.

Comment: Добавил. Странно, когда я писал код в keil, он не отмечал написанное, как ошибку. Но после того, как я перезапустил его, он выделил весь код красным. Разве такое может быть?

Comment: Скорее всего, проблема с включениями. Возможно, у вас в проекте есть конфигурационный файл, в котором можно включить-выключить include. Включите те заголовочные файлы, в которых определены идентификаторы, о которых компилятор вам сообщил.